# What is the geometric meaning of powers of the first Stiefel-Whitney class?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles, characteristic-classes

If $M$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold, I know $\\w_1^n(M)$ is a Stiefel-Whitney number of the manifold, but what does its vanishing geometrically mean?

More generally, does the Stiefel-Whitney height of $M$, i.e., the largest $k$ for which $\\w_1^k(M)\neq 0$, have a geometric meaning? (e.g. in terms of orientations)

Comment: $w_1^k(M)$ can be seen as a obstruction to a cross section in the $k$-fold whitney sum of the determinant line bundle associated to the tangent bundle. I don't know if this is something you were looking for.